# How to permanently unset PYTHONHOME environment variable in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, environment-variables

I cannot launch Python in Visual Studio because I am unable to unset the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable, which is permanently set to `C:\Python311` even after getting rid of it through windows control panel system environment editor, uninstalling Python311, and a full repair and reinstallation of Visual Studio.

### Problem

I have tried to unset `PYTHONHOME` through the usual Windows control panel system environment variable editor (locally and globally), but it does not solve the problem.

If I open a new PowerShell outside of Visual Studio and type `echo $ENV:PYTHONHOME`, the terminal outputs nothing, which is what I want.

However, when I type `echo $ENV:PYTHONHOME` in Visual Studio, it outputs `C:\Python311`. Why is it so? I tried to uninstall this Python version, but it doesn't solve the problem. I've also tried a full reinstallation of Visual Studio, but Visual Studio's powershell seems to load its own environment variables on top of the ones from Windows.

### Question

What should I do to permanently get rid of `PYTHONHOME` in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variables have [three scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.3):

1. Machine
2. User
3. Process

The environment variables follow the hierarchy *Machine -> User -> Process*, where the children overwrite the values of the environment variables inherited from the parents.

`PYTHONHOME` was in the "Process" scope and pertained to the Visual Studio environment.

To permanently clear `PYTHONHOME` from Visual Studio, open a Developer PowerShell in Visual Studio and execute the following command.

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", "")`

This should permanently clear `PYTHONHOME` from the current process.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to edit the .vcxproj file directly. The .vcxproj file is just an XML file so can be edited with a text editor. Open it up and search for "pythonhome".

Make sure to see which other lines in that file are trying to use PYTHONHOME and edit those accordingly.

Comment: I tried to have a look at the .vcxproj file, but there is no "PYTHONHOME" environment variable there. I think it's inside a very special location in the computer and is not project-related. For every project I work on, if I echo $ENV:PYTHONHOME in *Visual Studio* PowerShell/command shell, it outputs "C:\Python311". So I tried to completely uninstall Visual Studio, but the problem persists... When I tried to echo $ENV:PYTHONHOME on a PowerShell *outside* of Visual Studio, it outputs nothing. So the problem is related to the Visual Studio environment, but I don't know how the internals work.